# Java annotations and websocket - why are annotations used instead of traditional approach?

Tags: java, netbeans, websocket, annotations

Please look at the code I posted below. FYI, this is from the Oracle website's websocket sample:
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html

My question is, how does this work?! -- especially, the `broadcastFigure` function of `MyWhiteboard`. It is not a abstract function that is overridden and it is not "registered" with another class as in the traditional sense. The only way I see it is when the compiler sees the `@OnMessage` annotation, it goes and inserts the `broadcastFigure` call into the compiled code for when a new message is received. But before calling this function, it flows through the received data through the `FigureDecoder` class - based on this decoder being specified in the annotation `@ServerEndpoint`. Within `broadcastFigure`, when `sendObject` is called, the compiler inserts a reference to `FigureEncoder` - based on what's specified in the annotation `@ServerEndpoint`. Is this accurate?

If so, why did this implementation do things this way using annotations? Before looking at this, I would have expected there to be an abstract `OnMessage` function which needs to be overridden and explicit registration functions for Encoder and Decoder. Instead of such a "traditional" approach, why does the websocket implementation do it via annotations?

Thank you.

Mywhiteboard.java:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/whiteboardendpoint", encoders = {FigureEncoder.class}, decoders = {FigureDecoder.class})
public class MyWhiteboard {

    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnMessage
    public void broadcastFigure(Figure figure, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        System.out.println("broadcastFigure: " + figure);
        for (Session peer : peers) {
            if (!peer.equals(session)) {
                peer.getBasicRemote().sendObject(figure);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session peer) {
        peers.add(peer);
    }

}
```

FigureEncoder.java

```
public class FigureEncoder implements Encoder.Text<Figure> {

    @Override
    public String encode(Figure figure) throws EncodeException {
        return figure.getJson().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config) {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }

}
```

FigureDecoder.java:

```
public class FigureDecoder implements Decoder.Text<Figure> {

    @Override
    public Figure decode(String string) throws DecodeException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createReader(new StringReader(string)).readObject();
        return new Figure(jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willDecode(String string) {
        try {
            Json.createReader(new StringReader(string)).readObject();
            return true;
        } catch (JsonException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config) {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }

}
```

Comment: There is code somewhere else that looks for the OnMessage annotation using reflection.

Comment: Thanks immibis. Yeah, that's what I figured. But, from a design perspective, why do you think they did it that way instead of asking us to override an explicit OnMessage method? I am trying to understand the design rationale. Thx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations have their advantages and disadvantages, and there is a lot to say about choosing to create an annotation based API versus a (how you say) "traditional" API using interfaces. I won't go into that since you'll find plenty of wars online.

Used correctly, annotations provide better information about what a class/method's responsibility is. Many prefer annotations and as such they have become a trend and they are used everywhere.

With that out of the way, let's get back to your question:

> Why did this implementation do things this way using annotations? Before looking at this, I would have expected there to be an abstract OnMessage function which needs to be overridden and explicit registration functions for Encoder and Decoder. Instead of such a "traditional" approach, why does the websocket implementation do it via annotations?

Actually they don't. Annotation is just a provided way of using the API. If you don't like it then you can do it the old way. Here is from the JSR-356 spec:

> There are two main means by which an endpoint can be created. The first means is to implement certain of
>   the API classes from the Java WebSocket API with the required behavior to handle the endpoint lifecycle,
>   consume and send messages, publish itself, or connect to a peer. Often, this specification will refer to this
>   kind of endpoint as a programmatic endpoint. The second means is to decorate a Plain Old Java Object
>   (POJO) with certain of the annotations from the Java WebSocket API. The implementation then takes these
>   annotated classes and creates the appropriate objects at runtime to deploy the POJO as a websocket endpoint.
>   Often, this specification will refer to this kind of endpoint as an
>   annotated endpoint.

Again, people prefer using annotations and that's what you'll find most of tutorials using, but you can do without them if you want it bad enough.

Comment: Excellent. I followed up on what you said re: programmatic vs annotated endpoints and it's an interesting discussion. Cheers.

Comment: People prefer using annotations? Really? This approach prevents you from using compile-time type checks and auto-completion, whereas most other observer/listener kind of interfaces, you were able to work out what was available w/o having to dig into the documentation (e.g. [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) tells you straight away what kinds of events you can handle, and how to define the methods). Annotations here seem to prevent you from using what Java is good at, while never really giving you the flexibility of more relaxed lang.

Comment: @Bruno: I also have my issues with annotations, but as I said in the first paragraph of my answer, I won't go into stuff like that... just end with this: http://www.annotatiomania.com/ :)